Auto organize import compling with Flake8 (Python 3.11)
In a project, we enforce flake8 and black and we would like to have an auto-sorter of our imports, because it is  rather tedious and uninteresting task.
We tried isort, but out of the box it doesn't comply with flake 8. We tried using the black profile, not enough, and we tried using different options, but it was not complying.
The "best" shot we had was using this config:
[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
sections=['FUTURE', 'STDLIB', 'THIRDPARTY', 'FIRSTPARTY', 'LOCALFOLDER']
multi_line_output = 3
use_parentheses = true
order_by_type = true
only_sections = true
group_by_package = true
from_first = true
 

But it was still not compliant with flake8 because:

in the same section, packages are not separated by new lines,
and __future__ and STDLIB requires from imports in the end of the section, while other sections requires from imports at the begin of the section.

My question is:

Is there a config of isort that would comply with Flake8 + Black?
Alternatively, is there an import autosorter that would?


You should probably also show your flake8 configuration, and the errors you get. I would also recommend looking at Ruff instead of black + flake8 + isort.

presumably you're using some plugin to enforce import sorting.  if you're using a formatter to enforce that then there's no reason to also have a linter double check the results.  just disable the linter at that point
